# syntax error, unexpected ':' in site layout section of railstutorial.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm following a [RoR tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) and I'm following directions exactly (or so I think).

**This is my app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb file:**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<h1>Sample App</h1>

<p>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</p>

<%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "signup_button round" %>
```

When I run it in the local host, though, I get the error:

> sample_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected ':'
>   ...to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "signup_button round" );@outp...

I don't understand what I have to change and why. Any help?

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using? `{ class: 'foo' }` syntax for hashes was added in `1.9`. It won't work in earlier versions of ruby.

Comment: I was running 1.8, I tried changing it to <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', :class => "signup_button round" %> but I got even more errors. I just upgraded to 1.9.3, but my app is still running in 1.8. I don't know what is easier - to change the version of ruby in which the app is running, or modify my code so that it is allowed in 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby 1.9 allows

```
{foo: "bar"}
```

As an alternative to

```
{:foo => "bar"}
```

It looks you're running ruby 1.8 locally, hence the error. I'd recommend upgrading to ruby 1.9. Ruby 1.8 is on its way out.

Comment: I was running ruby 1.8. I just upgraded to ruby 1.9.3, but this app is still running version 1.8. Is it easier to change in which version the app runs, or modify my code so that it is allowed by 1.8?

Comment: The code change is trivial - you just need to change hashes using the new syntax. Running a newer version of ruby should also be easy once you've installed it, since the tutorial you are following clearly has ruby 1.9 in mind

Answer (score -1):

think i found it.

if you are running newer version of rails

it should be called

```
<%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', :class => "signup_button round" %>
```

instead of what you have there

Comment: Nothing to do with version of Rails, everything to do with version of Ruby

Comment: well, i guess he knows what i meant.